# Issue in convert calendar object to date android

Tags: android, date, calendar

I want to convert calendar object to date as follow.

```
int year,month,day;
mCalendarEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
year = mCalendarEnd.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = mCalendarEnd.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
day   = mCalendarEnd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Now convert it to date object

```
Date d1 = new Date(day,month,year);
```

when I print date object:

```
System.out.println("Date : "+d1.getDay()+"/"+d1.getMonth()+"/"+d1.getYear());
```

it should print current date but in above code it prints the wrong date. Any idea how can I solve this problem? your all suggestion are appreciable.

Comment: why you want to convert calendar object to date? as you are already getting dd-mm-yy from calendar object itself. Also the methods which you are trying to use is deprecated

Comment: Kinnar Vasa  : because i need day difference as per passing date object

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it like this

```
    //Set calendar
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date1 = calendar.getTime(); // gives a date object

    //To get day difference, Just an example
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
    Date date2 = calendar.getTime(); // gives a date object

    long differenceInMillis = Date1.getTime() - Date2.getTime();
    long differenceInDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(differenceInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Or No need of date objects

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long date1InMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
    long date2InMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    long differenceInMillis = date1InMillis - date2InMillis;
    long differenceInDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(differenceInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    calendar.getTimeInMillis()
```

Answer (score 3):

`calendar.getTime()` returns Date object.

but if you just need today date `new Date()` returns today date as Date object, too.

**Calendar example:**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
Log.i("My Tag", "calendar getTime -----> " + calendar.getTime());
```

**Output:**

```
My Tag: calendar getTime -----> Wed Dec 05 13:03:43 GMT+03:30 2018
```

**Date Example:**

```
Log.i("My Tag", "new Date -----> " + new Date());
```

**Output:**

```
My Tag: new Date -----> Wed Dec 05 13:05:38 GMT+03:30 2018
```

as you see both of them have the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your code:

```
Date d1 = new Date(year, month, day);
System.out.println("Date : " + d1.getDate() + "/" +d1.getMonth() + "/" + d1.getYear());
```

you will get the correct date.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use just the calendar?

```
System.out.println("Date   : " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
```

result 1/1/1900

or you want other format? but dont increment the month with 1

```
System.out.println("Date   : " + day + "/" + new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month] + "/" + year);
```

result 1/January/1900

Answer (score 0):

```
d1=new Date(year, month, day);
System.out.println("Dt:"+d1.getDate()+"/"+d1.getMonth()+"/"+d1.getYear());
```